# Outputting data to a grid control

Tags: c#, .net, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transferring data from string into a Data View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428306/transferring-data-from-string-into-a-data-view)

I am trying to get the data output into a DataGrid control, right now the output just goes into x number of TextBoxes. Any help would be appreciated

Code is as follows:

```
    foreach (string name in taskNames)
    {
        Task t = st.OpenTask(name);
        MessageBox.Show("  " + t.ToString());
        t.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just bind your output to the grid directly?  Just set the DataSource property to your collection and call DataBind on the grid.

Comment: Can you provide an example in this context please