# Transferring data from string into a Data View

Tags: c#, .net, windows, string

I am trying to transfer data from a string to a Data View control, could someone demonstrate how this could be done:

```
 private void testing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get a ScheduledTasks object for the computer named "DALLAS"
            string machineName = (@"\\" + System.Environment.MachineName);
            ScheduledTasks st = new ScheduledTasks(machineName);
            // Get an array of all the task names
            string[] taskNames = st.GetTaskNames();
            st.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: What data out of this set would you want to display?

Comment: @Frosty840 string name in taskNames

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < taskNames.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(taskNames[i]);    
}
```